# How to correctly define the Android StorageManager when using Koin's checkModules Test

Tags: android, unit-testing, koin, android-koin

I'm having issues running Koin's `checkModules` from JVM unit test. I cannot figure out the correct way to define/mock the Android's StorageManager as part of checking the modules. Using Koin 3.4.3.

I'm getting the error :

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Object cannot
> be cast to class android.os.storage.StorageManager (java.lang.Object
> is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap';
> android.os.storage.StorageManager is in unnamed module of loader
> 'app')

Here's the definition in question that's causing the issue:

```
single {
        MyFileManager(
            storageManager = androidContext().getSystemService(STORAGE_SERVICE) as StorageManager,
            appDirectory = androidContext().filesDir
        )
    }
```

Here's the checkModules call from my unit test. `allModules` is a list of the app's modules.

```
 koinApplication {
            modules(allModules)
            checkModules {
                withInstance<Context>()
                withInstance<Application>()
            }
        }
```